# Посчитать исходя из нажатых чекбоксов (товары)

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200?text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%201">
            <br>
            <p class="product-name">Продукт 1</p>
            <p class="product-price">150 руб</p>
            Количество
            <input type="number" value="1">
            <br> Выбрать
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200?text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%202">
            <br>
            <p class="product-name">Продукт 2</p>
            <p class="product-price">250 руб</p>
            Количество
            <input type="number" value="1">
            <br> Выбрать
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200?text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%203">
            <br>
            <p class="product-name">Продукт 3</p>
            <p class="product-price">350 руб</p>
            Количество
            <input type="number" value="1">
            <br> Выбрать
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p class="total-price">Тут итого</p>
```

Как можно посчитать сумму товаров при нажатии на чекбокс с количеством?

Comment: у вас уже есть какие либо наработки по этому вопросу? Что конкретно у вас не получается? Потому что сейчас ваш вопрос выглядит больше как задание

Comment: 'var total_price = 0;
function CalculateTotal(){
    $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            total_price += parseFloat($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $("#total_price").html(total);
}

$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
    total_price = 0;
    CalculateTotal();
}).trigger("change");'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант

```js
var checkBtns = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
var resultPrice = 0;
var resultPriceCont = document.querySelector('.total-price');
checkBtns.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var item = this.closest('td');
    var priceCont = item.querySelector('.product-price');
    var countCont = item.querySelector('input[type="number"]');
    var currentPrice = parseInt(countCont.value) * parseFloat(priceCont.innerText);
    if (this.checked) {
      countCont.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
      resultPrice += currentPrice;
    }
    else {
      countCont.removeAttribute('disabled');
      resultPrice -= currentPrice;
    }
    resultPriceCont.innerText = 'Итого: ' + resultPrice + ' руб.'
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200?text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%201">
            <br>
            <p class="product-name">Продукт 1</p>
            <p class="product-price">150 руб</p>
            Количество
            <input type="number" value="1">
            <br> Выбрать
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200?text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%202">
            <br>
            <p class="product-name">Продукт 2</p>
            <p class="product-price">250 руб</p>
            Количество
            <input type="number" value="1">
            <br> Выбрать
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200?text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%203">
            <br>
            <p class="product-name">Продукт 3</p>
            <p class="product-price">350 руб</p>
            Количество
            <input type="number" value="1">
            <br> Выбрать
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p class="total-price">Тут итого</p>
```